# How to send an angular param to an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here we go...
I have a controller

```
    $scope.selectedScript = {};
    $scope.selectedScript.scriptId = null;   


    $scope.selectScript = function(script, index) {
                    $scope.selectedScript = script;
                    $scope.selectedRow = index;

                    myAppFactory.updateTextArea(script).success(
                            function(data) {
                                $scope.selectedScript = data;
                            });
                };

    $scope.getSelectedClass = function(script) {
                    if ($scope.selectedScript.scriptId != undefined) {
                        if ($scope.selectedScript.scriptId == script.scriptId) {
                            return "selected";
                        }
                    }
                    return "";
                };
```

i have a html page

```
<label>Script ID:</label> 
<input name="scriptId" 
       type="text" 
       id="scriptId"
       ng-model="selectedScript.scriptId" 
       ng-disabled="true"
       value="{{selectedScript.scriptId}}" />
```

and now thx to IARKI i have this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goTo (){
 var param1 = angular.element(document.querySelector('.scriptId')).scope.selectedScript.scriptId;
 location.href=this.href + '?scriptId='+param1; 
 return false;
}
</script>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/DSS-war/debug.html" target="_blank" onclick="goTo()">Debug</a>
```

I have also a list of scripts in a table

```
<table class="scripts" name="tableScript" arrow-selector>
            <tr bgcolor="lightgrey">
                <th>Script ID</th>
                <th>File Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr
                ng-repeat="s in scripts | filter:searchField | orderBy:'scriptId'"
                ng-click="selectScript(s, $index)" ng-class="getSelectedClass(s)">
                <td>{{s.scriptId }}</td>
                <td>{{s.fileName }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Then i press the link above, and a new tab appears, but the link is still the

```
 http://localhost:8080/DSS-war/debug.html
```

but i need it to open in a new tab as well as to be like this:

```
 http://localhost:8080/DSS-war/debug.html?scriptId=1
 http://localhost:8080/DSS-war/debug.html?scriptId=2
 http://localhost:8080/DSS-war/debug.html?scriptId=12
```

and so on...with numbers

any idea?

And it has to be the onclick function, not the ng-click
I know how it works on ng-click, but i need to make it work on onclick...

and now i get this from the chrome debugger:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scriptId' of undefined
```

in the line

```
var param1 = angular.element(document.querySelector('.scriptId')).scope.selectedScript.scriptId;
```

Comment: Is `param1` in global scope? Why can't you specify `href`using angularjs?

Comment: *"has to be the onclick"* .... why? Ugly way to do things

Comment: i dont know if the param1 is global scope, how should i check it? and i have to make it work without the angular part, its required by the specifications

Comment: what do you mean by *"is required by the specifications"*? This whole thing sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: how should i say it, its a task set up by my professor...thats all...

Comment: well if you are going to work with angular, stay inside angular and don't start hacking in `onclick` or you are making things overcomplicated and difficult to test and debug. This is very simple to do using ng-click

Comment: can you call a function on onclick?

Comment: @IARKI that's a poor suggestion, `onclick` should be avoided

Comment: yes, i can call an alert for exemple

Comment: Okay so - what is your actual assignment/problem here? Is it an angular assignment or just a HTML/JS assignment? If you want to use angular, then use ng-click. If you were just given the task of sending some form data and can't use ng-click, don't use angular at all.

Comment: and i know it should be avoided, but i hope u can help me anyway

Comment: my assignment is to send somehow an angular variable with onclick from a href....thats all...

Comment: Well whatever, I'll bite. Where's your angular code?

Comment: my angular code is very simple, i have a script, that script has a scriptId thats all....nothing special

Comment: in my controler there is this line  $scope.selectedScript.scriptId = null;

Comment: and i have a list of scripts, once i select one the field updates, and gets a number

Comment: If you said you need to "make it work without the angular part", then just don't use angular, don't use any `ng-` things. Can you please post your actual assignment, word to word, since at the moment I'm having trouble believing your professor would give you an assignment like "send an angular variable to the server without ng-click"

Comment: @newb Can you please edit your post with a clear, full list of your requirements, and all of your current angular code - this isn't going anywhere since we don't have a clear idea of what you actually need to do.

Comment: done, see above

Comment: You still didn't post all of the angular code, you're just describing it - `"I have also a list of scripts in a table, once i press on one the selectedScript changes, and gets all the values, the name, the id, the src, the size and so on..."`. You also didn't post the actual requirements of your assignment, which is very frustrating to us, since we're suspecting you're asking for a solution to a problem that isn't your actual problem, see the `XY problem` link posted above. It's possible that you're unnecessarily trying to do things in a hard way when an easier solution would exist.

Comment: sry forgot about the table to add the code...but i can tell u, the part about selecting the values works...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to access angular scope using pure javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function goTo (){
     var param1 = angular.element("#scriptId").scope().selectedScript.scriptId;
     location.href=this.href + '?scriptId='+param1; 
     return false;
   }
</script>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/DSS-war/debug.html" target="_blank" onclick="goTo()">Debug</a>
```

**Update**
Useless code but I hope it will help you

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My application</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<label>Script ID:</label>
<input name="scriptId" type="text" id="scriptId" ng-model="selectedScript.scriptId" ng-disabled="true">
<button onclick="generateID()">Set code</button>
<a href="#" onclick="goTo()">Debug</a>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function generateID() {
        var code = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
        document.getElementById('scriptId').setAttribute('value', code.toString());
    }
    function goTo() {
        var scope = angular.element(document.querySelector('#scriptId')).scope();
        scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.selectedScript.scriptId = document.querySelector('#scriptId').getAttribute('value');
        });
        scope.changeURl();
    }
    angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
            $scope.selectedScript = {};
            console.log('We are in controller');
            $scope.changeURl = function () {
                $window.open('http://localhost:8080/DSS-war/debug.html?scriptId=' + $scope.selectedScript.scriptId, '_blank');
            }
        });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: it opens a new tab, but the same problem with the link http://localhost:8080/DSS-war/debug.html

Comment: i get this error once i use the code above: Uncaught Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/jqLite/nosel
    at angular.js:63
    at Object.JQLite [as element] (angular.js:2531)
    at goTo (index2.html:176)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (index2.html:181)

Comment: i removed the () from scope() and then there is a new error described above in the edited question

Comment: @newb take a look